# Search a DOM created from xml document and copy values to a spreadsheet/csv

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I have read a XML document into JAVA DOM data structure. I am able to search through the Document and find information using a For Loop. Then I can print out to the terminal all the information held within the parent and child nodes.

However what I need to be able to do is get certain elements and print them into a spreadsheet. So somehow writing the values to a csv doc that I can then import into Excel.

This would save me a lot of time as I would have to manually copy values into a spreadsheet which would takes me weeks. So automating it is the best option but I'm inexperienced in Java. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this with a single DOM parser instance can be quite cumbersome. For that I recommend to create a JavaBean which contains all the data from the xml file. A simple method called `toCsv` of that class will iterate over all items and returns you the formatted content or prints it to a csv file. 
If you follow this approach you can simply use the `Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB)` which will do the marshalling and unmarshalling between XML and Java- objects for you. There is no longer a need for a custom DOM parser implementation which is maybe hard to maintain. JAXB works with annotations, which defines parser rules. Here's a simple example:

```
public interface DataEntity {

    /**
     * NameSpace of XSD schema files.
     */
    public final static String NSP = "https://localhost/project/xsd/";

}


import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import at.fhj.ase.dao.data.validation.ValidationHelper;

/**
 * Represents a product category
 * 
 */
@XmlRootElement(name = "category", namespace = DataEntity.NSP)
public class Category implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -487248720383832971L;

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    protected Category() {

    }

    public Category(final Integer id, final String name,
            final String description) {
        setId(id);
        setName(name);
        setDescription(description);
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    private void setId(Integer id) {
        ValidationHelper.validateId(id);

        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement(namespace = DataEntity.NSP)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private void setName(String name) {
        ValidationHelper.validateSingleName(name, "name");

        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement(namespace = DataEntity.NSP)
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    private void setDescription(String description) {
        ValidationHelper.validateSingleName(description, "description");

        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Id: ").append(id).append(" Name: ").append(getName())
                .append(" Description: ").append(description);

        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

And the xml file as input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <category xmlns="https://localhost/project/xsd/" id="1">
    <description>des_swdevelopment</description>
    <name>swdevelopment</name>
</category>
```

And how to unmarshall from xml to java:
[Interface Unmarshaller](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html)

You just need to add the `toCsv` method and it is done. This approach will save you a lot of time and is quite easy to maintain.